# Is there a difference between _cdecl and __cdecl

Tags: c++

Is there any difference in using `_cdecl_` vs `__cdecl` (1 underscore vs 2 underscores) in function declaration?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with standard tools that comes with it.

Comment: The calling convention being specified is the same; just some compilers use one syntax instead of the other.

Comment: In which compiler? Using which standard library?

Comment: There is no difference.  The single underscore version is older, compilers writers had to standardize on two when too many libraries started using underscores as well.  So favor two.

Comment: When using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: This question is compiler specific. [One compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) supports __cdecl, the other may define [a macro](https://github.com/pakoito/desmume/blob/master/desmume/src/types.h#L154) and the other will use [`__attribute__((__cdecl__))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`__cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2017) is the default calling convention for C and C++ programs used by Microsoft  Compiler.

In fact, all of its [calling conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2017) follow the same pattern of double underscore before the name.

[`_cdecl_`](https://github.com/pakoito/desmume/blob/b51a094dd1ef3d4bd08be1627a641eac900868b9/desmume/src/types.h#L154) seems to be just another name for `__cdecl` defined using a macro.